# What's the source for movie Magneto's birthday?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, magneto

[This wiki article](http://marvel-movies.wikia.com/wiki/Erik_Lehnsherr) says that Erik Lehnsherr was born on January 30th 1930 but I don't know what this is based on!

Answer (score 1):

Probably [this article in The Vulture](https://www.vulture.com/2016/05/how-old-is-everyone-in-x-men-apocalypse.html)

> Take Magneto, who is just 14 years old when we meet him during World War II in a First Class prologue. Since that sequence takes place in 1944, we know the character was born around the year 1930.

It's dated May 27, 2016. The [revision to add his birth date was made on May 14, 2017](https://marvel-movies.fandom.com/wiki/Erik_Lehnsherr?oldid=189273). I can't figure out where The Vulture got it from, but the location came from [X-men: First Class](https://transcripts.fandom.com/wiki/X-Men:_First_Class)

> Erik: My parents were from Dusseldorf